# How put data in hashmap with duplicate keys but different values for jsoup post request?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, jsoup

I have some data values in a array list which is dynamically change based on selected item now i want to send that data to a post request using jsoup but problem is that every Singal values need to have same key. How i can achieve this?

Comment: what did you come up with so far ? do you have some code ?

Comment: Yes i have code but when i put arraylist data with that key and use it in post dat ait send only the last value in request

Comment: show the code with problem

Comment: Map is the key-value structure, where keys are unique. Therefore you can't put multiple same keys into the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use `Map` for this. However, with `.data(String, String)` (or most other `.data` overloads), you are not limited to one value per key.

```
Connection conn = JSoup.connect(url);
conn.data("foo", "bar");
conn.data("foo", "baz");
...
```

So either iterate on your list adding each element as a key-val pair as above, or map your list of values to an list of `HttpConnection.KeyVal.create(key, value)` then give it all to JSoup in one go with `conn.data(listOfKeyVals)`.

Comment: @amadan no i can't use in this way because NUMBER of values change based on selected item

Comment: That's why I wrote it this way instead of chained (which is more idiomatic): this way, you can use a LOOP.

Comment: Loop ? How?  i dont under stand can you  explain

Comment: `for (String rabbit : warren) { conn.data("rabbit", rabbit); }`. Or `warren.forEach(rabbit -> conn.data("rabbit", rabbit))`. Loop. The thing you use when you have a list of things and want to do similar things to each of them without repeating code.